# Postgres latency issues during memory compaction in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, memory

We've recently upgraded our EC2 instance that hosts our Postgres database to an i2.8xlarge with 244GB of memory (this is to utilise the large amounts of ephemeral storage it comes with). Since upgrading, we've been having some issues with latency in Postgres that appear to be due to memory compaction that's occurring in the Linux kernel.

We're using PostgreSQL 9.3 on a recent Ubuntu 14.04 kernel running the following (hopefully relevant subset of) config:

```
max_connections = 1000
effective_cache_size = '220GB'
shared_buffers = '24GB'
work_mem = '25MB'
maintenance_work_mem = '1024MB'
fsync = off
full_page_writes = on
synchronous_commit = off
```

We have transparent huge pages completely disabled on this server (`/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled` and `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag` are both set to `never` and `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/khugepaged/defrag` is set to `0`) and we're fairly sure that we're not seeing any issues as a result of THP because the `thp_*` stats and `nr_anon_transparent_hugepages` stat in `/proc/vmstat` never increment.

Our issue is that we see constant memory compaction (failure and success) events in `/proc/vmstat` (all the stats under `compact_*` incrementing frequently) and some of these cause pretty severe stalls that get worse over time (presumably as memory fragmentation gets worse) and impact on our application. We're tracking the stats from `/sys/kernel/debug/extfrag/unusable_index` and often see a flurry of movement between the different page orders when we see stall-causing events.

We're wondering whether this is just some combination of Postgres version, Linux kernel version and having to deal with a large amount of memory (as obviously most of the memory usage is file cache, so Linux might be doing things with that that Postgres isn't happy about), but haven't been able to come up with anything other than assuming a more recent version of Postgres (9.4 or 9.5) might avoid the issue altogether for some reason.

```
$ uname -a
Linux db-01 3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 17 20:50:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ dpkg -l postgresql-9.3
postgresql-9.3     9.3.12-1.pgdg14.04+1
```

Comment: Another thought we had with this - according to our settings, `effective_cache_size` + `shared_buffers` = total instance memory, so we're not sure if telling Postgres that most of the memory is being used for the file cache is efficient if `work_mem` needs to scale up during complex queries or when there are a lot of connections to the DB at one time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Out of curiosity, what size is the DB? Avg number of concurrent users? Max concurrent users? I assume you don't have the ability to test PostgreSQL 9.5.3 on the same scale of infrastructure? PostgreSQL 9.5 does come with a smaller session level footprint and more often than not they tend to not recommend > 500 user sessions without using some kind of pooling mechanism.

Comment: The data set is about 645GB. Average concurrent users is about 450, and max is about 600. We use pgbouncer session pooling for incoming connections, and this is capped at a pool size of 750, so slightly lower than the limit we've given Postgres.

Comment: Just to update, we tried lowering `effective_cache_size` to 160GB on a production replica that exhibits similar issues with the previous settings and it didn't make a difference (if anything it was slightly worse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a separate discussion on the DBA StackExchange it was suggested to try a non-Trusty (3.13) kernel, so we tested with the Xenial HWE (4.4) kernel on Trusty and things dramatically improved, so it appears to be due to (possibly later versions of the) 3.13 kernel in Trusty (we've been on this kernel for a while and only had problems more recently, so may have been something that was introduced).